# Comparison method violates general contract

Tags: java, android, comparator

I'm trying to use the following comparator and rarely but consistently I'm getting back an error of "comparison method violates general contract". I've tried debugging it several times but have never managed to find the root cause of this - are there any obvious issues here?

```
Collections.sort(ArrayListOfMyObjects, new Comparator<MyObject>() {

        public int compare(MyObject lhs, MyObject rhs) {          

            boolean lhsBool = lhs.getBooleanValueOfVariable;     

            boolean rhsBool = rhs.getBooleanValueOfVariable;          

            if (lhsBool && !rhsBool) {     

                return -1;     

            } else if (!lhsBool && rhsBool) {     

                return 1;          

            }
            // objects have no booleans defined

            else {          

                if (appGpsLocation == null) {          

                    String lhsString = lhs.getStringValueOfVariable();     

                    String rhsString = rhs.getStringValueOfVariable();          

                    return lhsString.compareTo(rhsString);     

                } else {          

                    float lhsFloat = lhs.getFloatValueOfVariable();

                    float rhsFloat = rhs.getFloatValueOfVariable();          

                    int result = Float.compare(lhsFloat, rhsFloat);          

                    return result;     
                }     
            }     
        }
});
```

Edits:

• (!useStrings) converted to -> (appHasGpsLocation == null)

• object method names changed to be more distinct from java methods

Comment: this: lhs.getObjectBoolean;  already makes no sense. Don't give variables method names please.

Comment: that's just for the purposes of the pseudocode to make the datatype obvious - my actual variable names are of course different.

Comment: How is `useStrings` initialized?

Comment: And what is it? Static field? Instance field?

Comment: @Jon: Whether it's in real code or just in a question, giving fields method-style names is confusing and not useful.

Comment: useStrings depends on whether the app has a current location or doesn't have it. I'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: Okay, so that just begs the question: What's `appGpsLocation`? A static field? An instance field? How does it get initialized? Does it change while objects are being compared?

Comment: @Jon so, you want us to check what the problem in your code is by showing us something that might logically look like how your code is?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. AppGpsLocation can change - it depends on another singleton that manages location data

Comment: @Stultuske I was just wondering if there was an issue with the way I was comparing the datatypes.. but actually T.J. Crowder's suggestion makes sense as to where the problem is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `appGpsLocation` doesn't change during the `sort`, then that method maintains the contract. But if `appGpsLocation` *changes* during the `sort`, then it may not, because suddenly it's using different information to determine the relation of the objects, and so it's possible that `a.compare(b)` and `b.compare(a)` won't mesh up, if `appGpsLocation` changed between them.

Comment: Many many thanks - that bug has been bothering me for about a year already. I'll make appGpsLocation into a local variable initialized before the sort is called, and then it's value can't change while the sort is in progress.